# When I type a URL in the address bar, then why does it always use "HTTP" and not some other protocol

Tags: http, web

I want to understand http protocol in depth. Does anyone know where can I find relevant material for HTTP. A few questions that I have in particular are:

1. Why does when press enter after typing for eg. "google.com" it gets translated to "http://www.google.com" and not "ftp://www.google.com" or something else.
2. How does the http request gets transferred to a server, what routing algorithm it uses to decide which server to used, and inside that server where to locate the uniform resource".

Any pointers in this direction are most welcome!!

Comment: Thats a big answer you are looking for, it could even contain volumes of articles. But this might help you understand a little about URL, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uniform_resource_locator and also this might help.. http://www.amazon.com/Computer-Networks-Edition-Andrew-Tanenbaum/dp/0132126958


BTW, `Ctrl + Enter` padding with `http` is not a standard, its just the browser supports it. Its the feature of the browser application not any standard of www or internet.

Comment: Number 1 is purely about *browser* implementations - it's nothing to do with the HTTP protocol. Also, most browsers I've used will not add a `www.` prefix on without more action than purely hitting enter. Otherwise, it would be difficult to reach e.g. this site.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: So you mean that depending on a browser implementation, it can also default to "ftp" in some particular case?

Comment: It could. But, of course, 100% (within rounding errors) of addresses that are entered in are intended to be used with HTTP so if you don't specify a protocol, a sound guess by the browser is that the user intended HTTP.

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever: Okies..thanks for the info.. thanks to you too Mahmud.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because HTTP is simply the web standard for requests. We all agreed on using that when the web started, and now we are stuck with it (whether it is good or not).

HTTP stands for 'Hypertext Transfer Protocol' and is in fact the way how to exchange that information you see on your display when browsing.

FTP, and numerous other protocols are *their* standards (or in general methods) for their purpose. HTTP serves the purpose of communicating between client and server for the web.

And about *how* HTTP works internally, well, they wrote a few books on it. The standard is described by the IETF: [Hypertext Transfer Protocol -- HTTP/1.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2616).

Comment: Yeah, your are right. I also found the exact answer I was looking for at this URL: "http://www.webopedia.com/TERM/H/HTTP.html".

Comment: "The" standard is a work product of the IETF, not the W3C. Also note that RFC 2616 is going to be replaced by a new set of documents very soon now. <See http://tools.ietf.org/wg/httpbis/>.

Comment: @PatrickHofman - I still think it would be better to point people to the spec published on the IETF site...